# Cordova Plugin-File Android Q Permissions Error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, android-10.0

So Android 10 broke Cordovas plugin file as it gives permission errors relating to this change: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage

I came across this possible solution https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3896 but Cordova does not seem to support it.

The following config.xml produces an error

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:allowBackup="false" />
        <application android:fullBackupContent="false" />
        <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />
    </edit-config>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^8.1.0" />
</widget>
```

`../debug/AndroidManifest.xml:22: AAPT: error: attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found.`

My Android studio shows the latest sdks being used.

Comment: i am facing same issue, how did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Check below lines in `build.gradle` file

```
project.ext {defaultBuildToolsVersion=29 defaultMinSdkVersion=19 defaultTargetSdkVersion=29 defaultCompileSdkVersion=29}
```